# Which symmetry for which distance function

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, coordinate-systems

For evaluating the electric field of some charge distribution one can use $$\phi(r):= \frac{1}{4 \pi \varepsilon_0}\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \frac{\rho(r')}{||r-r'||_2} dr'.$$

My question is: What symmetry do we need to have that we can write in spherical coordinates $$||r-r'||_2 = \sqrt{||r||_2^2+||r'||_2^2-2||r||_2||r'||_2\cos(\theta')}~?$$

This is of course not the most general way to express this distance, as the $\phi$ dependence is missing. So, under what conditions can the distance be expressed like this?

Notice that $\theta'$ is the respective angle in spherical coordinates, so it's NOT the angle between $r$ and $r'$.

So in particular, your answer should clarify, why we can evaluate for example the electric potential of a sphere by integrating: $$\frac{1}{4 \pi \varepsilon_0} \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi \int_0^{\infty}  \frac{\rho(r')||r'^2|| sin(\theta')}{\sqrt{||r||_2^2+||r'||_2^2-2||r||_2||r'||_2\cos(\theta')}}d||r'||_2 d\theta'd\phi',$$ but need to refer to a more general equation in this example, where the $\phi$ angle is used too: [excercise 14b)](http://aforrester.bol.ucla.edu/comprobs/F06prob14.pdf)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question so I'll just leave a comment. First, the $\phi$ is the *electrostatic* potential for a stationary distribution of charges $\rho$. The formula for the distance is simply the cosine theorem, which is proved in Euclid's Elements :-) How do you define $||r-r'||_2$?

Comment: $||r-r'||_2 = \sqrt{(x-x')^2+(y-y')^2+(z-z')^2}$.

Comment: It is assumed that either $r$ is directed along $z$ or that $\theta'$ is the angle between $r$ and $r'$ and not the polar angle.

Comment: Try to give a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines - As V.Moretti points out maybe your confusion arises from the fact that $\theta '$ in the formula is the angle beetween $r$ and $r'$... in that case, the law of cosines is the theorem.

Comment: @V.Moretti ah, so it works for the sphere, because in that case, the potential in $z-$ direction is the same as in any other direction?

Comment: @pppqqq actually no, it was supposed to denote the $\theta$ that you know from spherical coordinates.

Comment: Ah I see. So you are looking for a simmetry in the distribution that lets you evaluate the integral as if $r$ was along the $z$-axis. I'm not sure such distribution exists... I'll see if I can find a proof!

Comment: pppqqq's answer/comment is correct, this is the theorem of cosines, since this is a homework, maybe this is in 2-dimensional Euclidean space? Furthermore $\phi$ is not involved in the distance between r1 and r2, this is just a vector distance between 2 vectors. The symmetry is spherical symmetry (which holds since the radiation expands in spherical way, "homogeneous space")

Comment: @NikosM. the intersection between my question and your answer is empty!

Comment: @V.Moretti could you explain somewhat more what you meant by: r has to be directed along the $z-$ axis? I mean, if I calculate the electric field $$E(r)=  \frac{1}{4 \pi \varepsilon_0} \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \frac{\rho(r')}{||r-r||}(r-r')?$$ I get the right answer and this field is not just the one on the $z-$axis but the right field in the whole space.

Comment: I do not know: I admit that I cannot understand your original question since $||r-r'||_2 = \sqrt{||r||_2^2+||r'||_2^2-2||r||_2||r'||_2\cos(\theta')}$ is valid for every $r,r'$ only if $\theta'$ is the angle between $r$ and $r'$.

Comment: @V.Moretti no $\theta'$ is NOT the angle between these two vectors it is the angle component of the second one( $r = (||r||,\theta, \phi)$ and $r'= (||r'||,\theta',\phi')$)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is that $\rho$ must be  spherically symmetric (necessary and sufficient condition).

To show it, let me change notation. Now $r$ ad $r'$ are the absolute values of the vectors $\vec{r}$,$\vec{r'}$ and we know that
$$\phi(\vec{r}):= \frac{1}{4 \pi \varepsilon_0}\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \frac{\rho(\vec{r'})}{||\vec{r}-\vec{r'}||_2} dr'.\tag{0}$$
where  $$||\vec{r}-\vec{r'}||_2 = \sqrt{r^2+{r'}^2-2rr'\cos(\theta')}\tag{1}\:,$$
$\theta'$ being the polar angle of $\vec{r'}$.

From the general theory we know that it also hold
$$\phi(\vec{r}):= \frac{1}{4 \pi \varepsilon_0}\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \frac{\rho(\vec{r'})}{||\vec{r}-\vec{r'}||} dr'\tag{2}$$
where 
$$||\vec{r}-\vec{r'}|| = \sqrt{r^2+{r'}^2-2rr'\cos(\alpha)}\tag{3}\:,$$
$\alpha$ being the angle between $\vec{r'}$ and $\vec{r}$.
Comparing (1) and (3), we conclude that 
$$\phi(\vec{r})= \phi(r \vec{e}_z)= f(r)$$
Consequently we have that
$$\phi(\vec{r}) = f(r)\:.$$
Since, for some constant depending on the unit system, $\kappa \Delta \phi(\vec{r}) = \rho(\vec{r})$, we have that
$$\rho(\vec{r}) = \kappa \Delta f(r)\:.$$
In other words $\rho$ must necessarily be a spherically symmetric function.

The found condition is also sufficient. Indeed, if $\rho$ is spherically symmetric, using the rotational invariance of the measure and the standard distance, it easily arises that the right-hand side of (2) can be re-written as the right-hand side of (0):
$$\phi(\vec{r}):= \frac{1}{4 \pi \varepsilon_0}\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \frac{\rho(\vec{r'})}{||\vec{r}-\vec{r'}||} dr' = \frac{1}{4 \pi \varepsilon_0}\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \frac{\rho(\vec{Rr'})}{||\vec{r}-\vec{Rr'}||} dRr'=
\frac{1}{4 \pi \varepsilon_0}\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \frac{\rho(\vec{r'})}{||\vec{r}-\vec{Rr'}||} dr'=  \frac{1}{4 \pi \varepsilon_0}\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \frac{\rho(\vec{r'})}{||\vec{R^{-1}r}-\vec{r'}||} dr' =
 \frac{1}{4 \pi \varepsilon_0}\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \frac{\rho(\vec{r'})}{||r\vec{e}_z-\vec{r'}||} dr' = \frac{1}{4 \pi \varepsilon_0}\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \frac{\rho(\vec{r'})}{||\vec{r}-\vec{r'}||_2} dr'\:.$$